# Prevent hotlinking specific files with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, hotlinking

How can I prevent hotlinking specific files from other sites?
Lets say `mydomain.com/file1.zip` and `mydomain.com/file2.zip` - I would like to redirect them to pages `mydomain.com/file1page` and `mydomain.com/file2page`.
I want to prevent only those 2 of hotlinking not all the zip files.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can check against the referer but those can easily be spoofed. So something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mydomain.com/
RewriteRUle ^/?(file1|file2).zip$ /$1page [L,R=302]
```

So if the referer *doesn't* start with `http://mydomain.com/` and the request is for either `file1.zip` or `file2.zip`, redirect to either `file1page` or `file2page`.